# show api console log in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

```js
function refreshData(e) {
  const nameOfAnime = e.target.value;
  const url = `https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/nyaa/anime?query=${nameOfAnime}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(console.log);
}

const input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("change", refreshData);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  rel="stylesheet" 
  integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<title>AnimeFinder</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="input" type="text" value="input"/>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

currently the info is logged into the console but i want it to be shown to user. i tried using innerHTML but it did not work

Comment: You'll have to format the JSON in order to make it readable for a user.

Comment: sorry i didnt quite understand?should i use stringify?because i tried that but i dont know how to show the log to the user without opening dev tools

Comment: Hey, I just posted an answer with a demo showing what I mean. Check it out, and let me know if you need any clarification! Also, would you please consider marking my answer as correct if it meets your expectations?

Comment: sorry im pretty late but i had some work...I will check out your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the data into a table:

```js
var currentQuery = "";

var inputElement = document.getElementsByClassName("anime-input")[0];
inputElement.addEventListener("input", refreshData);
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"))

function refreshData(e) {
  //Deal with fetching delay
  currentQuery = inputElement.value;
  var thisQuery = inputElement.value;
  //Hide table, show loading
  document.getElementsByClassName("show-hide")[0].style.display = "block"
  document.getElementsByClassName("show-hide")[1].style.display = "none"

  var query = (e.target.value == "") ? query = e.target.placeholder : e.target.value;
  fetch("https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/nyaa/anime?query=" + query)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      //Deal with fetching delay
      if (thisQuery != currentQuery) {
        return;
      }
      //Initialize column data variables
      var titles = [],
        sizes = [],
        torrents = [],
        dataSize = data.data.length;

      //Arrange the data to appropriate array
      data.data.forEach(dataPoint => {
        titles.push(dataPoint.title);
        sizes.push(dataPoint.size);
        torrents.push(dataPoint.torrent)
      });

      //Clear table
      document.getElementsByClassName("anime-data")[0].innerHTML = "";

      //Put the data in the table
      [...Array(dataSize)].forEach((el, index) => {
        row = document.createElement("tr")
        var title = document.createElement("td")
        title.innerText = titles[index]
        row.appendChild(title)
        var size = document.createElement("td")
        size.innerText = sizes[index]
        row.appendChild(size)
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("td")
        downloadLink.innerText = torrents[index]
        row.appendChild(downloadLink)

        document.getElementsByClassName("anime-data")[0].appendChild(row)
      })

      //Hide loading, show table
      document.getElementsByClassName("show-hide")[0].style.display = "none"
      document.getElementsByClassName("show-hide")[1].style.display = "block"
    })
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  Enter Name of Anime:
  <input class="anime-input" type="text" placeholder="Hanasaku Owari">
  <br><br>
  <span class="show-hide">Loading...</span>
  <table class="show-hide">
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width:45%;border: 1px black solid">
      <col style="width:10%;border: 1px black solid">
      <col style="width:45%;border: 1px black solid">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <th style="">Title</th>
      <th style="">Size</th>
      <th style="">Torrent Download</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody class="anime-data">
      <tr>
        <td class="anime-title"></td>
        <td class="anime-download-size"></td>
        <td class="anime-download-link"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

While I only did a few data points, you can expand the concept to include more.

Comment: are the "..." in [...Array(dataSize)] used or its an error? because vscode says its unexpected...after deleting it the console is showing a CORS error and theres a loading sign which doesnt go away (probably because of the CORS error

Thanks for using your time to help me!!

Comment: its 80% something from the API side

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you need any clarification on any of the code. Also, in my browser/computer `Array().forEach` does not work, but apparently, if I expand it into square brackets it works. If I'm being honest, I have no idea why it does not work, and the internet isn't of much help with this issue either.

Comment: its something with the api thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hey! the api is back online but the code is still showing a CORS error? I added a the necessary header but it still isnt working

Comment: Try going through this article: https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the response as a string you can do the following using `JSON.stringify()` and `innerText`:

```js
const pre = document.querySelector("pre");

function refreshData(e) {
  const nameOfAnime = e.target.value;
  const url = `https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/nyaa/anime?query=${nameOfAnime}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(res));
}

const input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("change", refreshData);
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="input" />
<pre></pre>
```